# CSS horizontal centering, and min-height not working in IE

Tags: css, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="content" style="background-color: white;">
        ...   
    </div>    
</div>

#content{
  float: left;
  width: 540px;
  padding: 30px 30px 0px 30px;
  background-color:#19252f;
  text-align: left;
  min-height: 500px;
}
#wrapper {
   margin: 0 auto;
   width: 800px;
}
```

[image: Firefox look]

Firefox look

[image: Internet Explorer 8 look]
Internet Explorer 8 look

Comment: Can you post your code online so I can see it working?

Comment: Do you have a doctype declaration on your page?

Comment: @Seth: I forget the site that allow you to post the html and css code and generate the page look. Can u refresh my memory? @BoltClock: here is my Doctype: `<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">`

Comment: Is your question: "how do I get the same behavior in IE as I see in FF?"

Comment: @kbrimington: Yes, that is exactly my quesion. Sorry for the confusion

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. margin:auto horizontal centering is not supported in IE6. Instead you can either use absolute positioning to center or you can do

   body{
   text-align:center;
   }
2. For IE min-height you need to add the hacked property `_height: 300px` in addition to `min-height: 300px;` 
   All browsers but IE will ignore the hacked property, and since IE effectively treats height as min-height, you’ll get the effect that you want in all browsers.
3. `background-color` works in IE without any problems.

Comment: @harry Some people have a habit of down voting. There is nothing wrong with the post. Ignore the down vote. You can upvote it to remove the negative.

Comment: 1) IE6 does support `margin: auto` in standards mode. 2) The screenshot here is IE8, not IE6, so it supports `min-height` just fine. I didn't downvote, but this could be why.

Comment: I didn't realize he was using IE8. Either way try the workarounds i provided and let me know how it works out. It's vary hard to tell what's going on without seeing any code. These were valid suggestions that will also make the site work in IE6.